# Swedish characters in Pandas and lists

Tags: pandas, special-characters

I'm using Python 2.7 and Pandas and have a problem with Swedish characters. The Swedish characters works in Pandas but when I create a list from the dataframe something gets wrong:

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'name': ['Åberg', 'Östlund', 'Älberg', 'Ericsson'],
     'age': [22,38,26,35] 
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    print(df)


   age      name
0   22     Åberg
1   38   Östlund
2   26    Älberg
3   35  Ericsson

df['name'].tolist()

['\xc3\x85berg', '\xc3\x96stlund', '\xc3\x84lberg', 'Ericsson']
```

Any idea how to keep the Swedish characters in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are kept in the list, BUT python 2 renders the unicode strings. You can see this by printing each value:

```
In [11]: for name in df.name.tolist(): print(name)
Åberg
Östlund
Älberg
Ericsson
```

You can render the joined list with join:

```
In [12]: print(", ".join(df.name.tolist()))
Åberg, Östlund, Älberg, Ericsson
```

You *may* want to explicitly ensure they are unicode with:

```
In [13]: [n.decode("utf-8") for n in df.name.tolist()]
Out[13]: [u'\xc5berg', u'\xd6stlund', u'\xc4lberg', u'Ericsson']
```

but as you can see, they are still going to render awkwardly.

(The best solution is to update to python 3! ;) )

---

Note: Python 3 renders these unicodes as you'd expect in the list:

```
In [31]: df.name.tolist()
Out[31]: ['Åberg', 'Östlund', 'Älberg', 'Ericsson']
```